# Single column SUM, not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to know why in this query:

```
SELECT 100 * (select sum(s.bytes)
                from dba_segments s
                where TABLESPACE_NAME='USERS') / sum(MAXBYTES) used
FROM dba_data_files
WHERE tablespace_name = 'USERS'
```

I'm getting

> not a single-group group function error

I could fix it by adding `GROUP BY tablespace_name` at the end, but I don't understand why it's needed.

Also tried something like putting subselect inside of MAX but error changed to

> Missing expression

**Edit:**

Expected result: 1 decimal between 0 and 100. (4.43725586 with results below)
I wanted to divide results of 2 queries and multiple it by 100 at once.

First query to get actual size:

```
select sum(s.bytes)
from dba_segments s
where TABLESPACE_NAME='USERS'
```

Result: 524091392

Second query to get maximum size:

```
select sum(MAXBYTES)
FROM dba_data_files
WHERE tablespace_name = 'USERS'
```

Result: 1.1811E+10

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a parsing bug in Oracle.  The following fails with the same message:

```
SELECT 100 * (select sum(s.bytes)
              from dba_segments s
             ) / sum(df.MAXBYTES) as used
FROM dba_data_files df
WHERE df.tablespace_name = 'USERS';
```

However, this fixes the issue:

```
SELECT 100 * (select sum(s.bytes)
                from dba_segments s
                where s.TABLESPACE_NAME = 'USERS'
             ) / sum(df.MAXBYTES) as used
FROM dba_data_files df
WHERE df.tablespace_name = 'USERS'
GROUP BY 'a';  -- a constant here
```

The subquery is uncorrelated, so it *should* be allowed.  However, Oracle appears to be disallowing it in the version with no `GROUP BY`.

As for a solution, I would be inclined to move the two subqueries to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT (100 * segment_bytes / df_bytes) as used
FROM (select sum(df.MAXBYTES) as df_bytes
      from dba_data_files df
      where df.TABLESPACE_NAME = 'USERS'
     ) df CROSS JOIN
     (select sum(s.bytes) as segment_bytes
      from dba_segments s
      where s.TABLESPACE_NAME = 'USERS'
     ) s;
```

Comment: Why cross join? So you wouldn't need to add on condition?

Comment: @Tundy . . . Because a `cross join` is appropriate in this case where the two subqueries each return exactly one row.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a JOIN between two derived tables instead:

```
select 100 * (s.used_bytes / df.maxbytes) as used_pct
from (
  select tablespace_name, sum(maxbytes) as maxbytes
  from dba_data_files 
  group by tablespace_name
) df
  join (
    select tablespace_name, sum(bytes) as used_bytes
    from dba_segments 
    group by tablespace_name
  ) s on s.tablespace_name = df.tablespace_name
where s.tablespace_name = 'USERS';
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an embedded sub-select like this, Oracle isn't able to understand that you're pulling data for a single tablespace and insists on being given a `GROUP BY`.

If you change the query to use a join, with the tablespace name given in the `WHERE` clause, you can avoid the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 100 * COALESCE(SUM(s.BYTES), SUM(f.BYTES))
         / COALESCE(NULLIF(SUM(f.MAXBYTES), 0), NULLIF(SUM(f.BYTES), 0)) used
  FROM DBA_DATA_FILES f
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DBA_SEGMENTS s
    ON s.TABLESPACE_NAME = f.TABLESPACE_NAME
  WHERE f.TABLESPACE_NAME = 'USERS'
```

I modified the initial query to handle the issue of `SUM(f.MAXBYTES)` coming out to zero, which it does on my system, which leads to a "divisor is zero" error.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer, why there has to be GROUP BY & information about zero.
But your query sum duplicates (or something like that) so results are wrong. I used @a_horse_with_no_name in the end.
But don't know which answer should I mark now.

Answer (score 0):

because your subselect is like you have  a  not aggregated  result for the first column 
try using

```
SELECT 100 * ( select sum(s.bytes) 
from dba_segments s 
where TABLESPACE_NAME='USERS')  / sum(MAXBYTES) used
FROM dba_data_files
WHERE tablespace_name = 'USERS'
group by 100 * ( select sum(s.bytes) 
from dba_segments s 
where TABLESPACE_NAME='USERS')
```